# How to upload different images size for each custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a Wordpress website with 3 custom post type(User, Event, Gallery).
Each custom post type have a different image size like:
- User 500 x 400px;
- Event 1000 x 300px;
- Gallery 1500 x 1500px;

If I only use the add_image_size with each size after I upload an image it will generate this 3 size for each image and I only need one.

I already tried a one solution like:

```php
add_filter( 'intermediate_image_sizes', 'custompostUser', 999 );  
function custompostUser( $image_sizes ){  

    $slider_image_sizes = array( 'userSize');   

    if( isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) && 'user' === get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post_id'] ) )  
        return $slider_image_sizes;  

    return $image_sizes;  
}  

add_image_size('userSize',500,400);
```

After upload any image on other post type it will generate the wrong image

I only need to generate one image for each custom post type not three images